# How to find the smallest element in a number using a recursion [C]

Tags: c, recursion

ok so I am preparing for my C exams and I'm a bit stuck when it comes to recursions I'm a freshman at my university and this seems a bit difficult to me, the exercise requires that in a given number using a recursive function I need to find the smallest element, ex:52873 would be 2 and the program would need to print 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int min (int number, int element){
        if (number==0)
            return element;
        if (element>number%10)
            element=number%10;

        min(number/10,element);
    }

    int main (){
        int number;
        while (scanf("%d",&number)){
            printf("%d\n",min(number,9));

        }
    }
```

this is the code for the answer of the exercise but I do not understand it and would love to get some insight on why it is solved like this since I don't really understand it and different ways to solve it, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but terminology matters. What you mean is to find the smallest *digit* in a number.

Comment: look at the compiler warnings: http://ideone.com/CZ9Qf5

Comment: As for your problem and the code you show, you probably don't understand it because it *doesn't work!* You have a function, `min`, which is declared to return a value. But there are cases where it *doesn't* return a value, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: digit is what I meant that is correct but as for the code itself it fulfills it's task, the program is suppose to end when the user enters something that isn't a number I forgot to add that

Comment: `min(number/10,element);` should be `return min(number/10,element);`.

Comment: If you enter something which isn't a number (like say the letter `x`) then the [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function will return zero and the loop should end. However, if you press the end-of-file key-combination (`Ctrl-D` on Linux/macOS, `Ctrl-Z` on Windows) then [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) return `EOF` which is *not* zero and the loop will not end.

Comment: what I wanted to know was why the code is written like this and what the logic behind this recursion is because I really don't understand it

Comment: Why don't you try working out an example on paper?  Trace the arguments to and behavior of each call in your recursive stack as it works through one input.

Comment: Start by writing the algorithm with a plain, readable loop. Once you have a proper program working, obfuscate the code by adding the slow, dangerous, unreadable recursion, so that your program turns bad as per requirements.

Comment: So you didn't write the code, you just found it, and are wondering how it works? Well then that brings us back to the point that it *doesn't*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int min (int number, int element){
    if (number==0)
        return element;
    if (element>number%10)
        element=number%10;

    min(number/10,element);
}
```

Here, your recursive function has two arguments. `int number` which stores the number of which the least element is to be obtained and `int element` to store the least element.

In each call, you check the following two conditions:

- `if (number > 0)` then return `element`.
- `if (element > number%10)`. Here, `number % 10` denotes the last number of the `number` and it's compared against `element` which is initially set to `9`. If the `number % 10` is less than `element`, then the value of the element is set to `number % 10`.

After the above process, you recursively call the function with the values `number / 10` and `element`. The reason why you call `number \ 10` is because it removes the last digit from the `number` which was already checked for in the previous call.

And finally, this process goes on till you have no digits are left i.e, `number` becomes zero.

**Example:** take `min(1234, 9)` as the call from `main()` function.

1. call from `main()` function

   ```
   number = 1234
   element = 9

   since number != 0 continue;

   since, 1234 % 10 i.e, 4 < 9, element is set to 4
   ```

   and the function is recursively called with values `number = 1234 / 10 = 123` and `element = 4`
2. first recursive function call:

   ```
   number = 123
   element = 4

   since number != 0 continue;

   since, 123 % 10 i.e, 3 < 4, element is set to 3
   ```

   and the function is recursively called with values `number = 123 / 10 = 12` and `element = 3`
3. second recursive function call:

   ```
   number = 12
   element = 3

   since number != 0 continue;.

   since, 12 % 10 i.e, 2 < 3, element is set to 2

   and the function is recursively called with values `number = 12 / 10 = 1` and `element = 2`
   ```
4. third recursive function call:

   ```
   number = 1
   element = 2

   since number != 0 continue;

   since, 1 % 10 i.e, 1 < 2, element is set to 1
   ```

   and the function is recursively called with values `number = 1 / 10 = 0` and `element = 1`
5. finally in the fourth and last recursive call:

   ```
   number = 0
   element = 1

   since `number = 0`, the value of the `element` i.e, `1` is returned.
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the program is the following:

when you % a number by 10, you get the last digit, ex:

```
16%10 = 6;
6%10 = 6;
536%10 = 6;
```

When you / a number by 10, you take out of the number the last digit, ex:

```
16/10 = 1;
6/10 = 0; (6 = 06)
536/10 = 53;
```

So, the idea of your recursive answer is save in "element" the smallest digit, and analyse each digit recursively by dividing the number by 10 (/) and doing module (%).

But, i think your solution have a problem, if my number is 0, you'll return 9 as answer.

Answer (score 1):

For More Clearity Let's See a Example

How recursion works

let's element=9

it every time check last digit

```
min(9154,element)                       -----first call
if(element>4)       
    element=4       -------//now element is 4               
        min(915,element)    -------9154/10=  915        ------second call

        if(element>5)   ------here element is 4 so  no update

                min(91,element)  ------915/10=91        ------third call

                if(element>1)
                      element=1   ---------now element is 1
                       min(9,element)       ---------91/10=9    -----fourth call

                       if(9>element)     ---------no update 
                            min(0,element)   ------9/10=0  
                        //since become 0 so it return element
```

Answer (score 0):

find the lowest digit of an integer > 0 using recursion:

```
int min_digit_rec(int num)
{
if (num < 10)
    return num;
else    
        {
            int l_digit;
            int r = min_digit_rec(num / 10);
            
            l_digit = num % 10;
            return r < l_digit ? r : l_digit;
        }
    
}
```