# find the min digit in a recursive function

Tags: recursion, minimum

ok so I am preparing for my C exams and I'm a bit stuck when it comes to recursions I'm a freshman at my college and this seems a bit difficult to me, the exercise requires that in a given number using a recursive function I need to find the smallest element, ex:52873 would be 2 and the program would need to print 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int min_digit_rec(int num)
{
    int min=num;
    if (num == 0)
        return min;
    if (min>num%10)
        min = num % 10;
    
    min=min_digit_rec(num/10);

void main()
{
   int num, min_dig2;
    printf("Enter an integer number\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    min_dig2 = min_digit_rec(num);
    printf("output: the smallest digit from min_digit_rec: %d\n", min_dig2);
       
}
```

this is the code for the answer of the exercise but it does not work well and I don't understand why..can someone explain to me what am I missing?,
thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Here is the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41486547/how-to-find-the-smallest-element-in-a-number-using-a-recursion-c/41486965) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the solution of your problem in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
void showContentVector(std::vector<int>& input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<input[i]<<", ";
    }
    return;
}
void minimumDigit(int number, int& minimum, std::vector<int>& input)
{
    if(number==0)
    {
        minimum=input[0];
        for(int i=1; i<input.size(); ++i)
        {
            minimum=std::min(minimum, input[i]);
        }
        return;
    }
    input.push_back(number%10);
    minimumDigit(number/10, minimum, input);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> inputVector;
    int minimumNumber;
    minimumDigit(52873, minimumNumber, inputVector);
    std::cout<<"minimumNumber <- "<<minimumNumber<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
minimumNumber <- 2
```